# External Table in ADX for ADLS data : No records

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have Log data being stored at ADLS gen 2 storage . I am trying to query it in ADX , therefore i created an External table in ADX but the records are not populating here. I get no records in ADX external table.

**Created External Table:**

```
.create external table extable1 (AppId:string) 
kind=blob
dataformat=json
( 
   h@'https://clickstreamstorelake2.blob.core.windows.net/streamout/0_56da70eca49745f8b830da45ff6aba57_1.json;secret_key_here'
)
with 
(
   docstring = "Docs",
   folder = "ExternalTables",
   namePrefix="Prefix"
)
```

**Json Mapping**

```
.create external table extable1 json mapping "map1" '[{ "column" : "AppId", "datatype" : "string", "path" : "$.AppId"}]'
```

***ADLS gen 2 file***
[image: Json File in ADLS gen 2]

Comment: How are you querying the table? you need to use external_table('tablename') to get the data, see more here https://kusto.azurewebsites.net/docs/query/externaltablefunction.html

Comment: i have tried - external_table('extable1'  , 'map1')  and  external_table('extable1' )   but no data , it does not throw any error though .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong "nameprefix" parameter was passed which caused the no records.

**namePrefix :  string  If set, indicates the prefix of the blobs. On write operations, all blobs will be written with this prefix. On read operations, only blobs with this prefix are read.**

It should be in accordance with the blobs present in ADLS.

Below code works well if there is no nameprefix set in ADLS container.

```
.create external table extable1 (AppId:string) 
kind=blob
dataformat=json
( 
   h@'https://clickstreamstorelake2.blob.core.windows.net/streamout/0_56da70eca49745f8b830da45ff6aba57_1.json;secret_key_here'
)
with 
(
   folder = "ExternalTables"
)
```